# finding the max integer from scattered data types, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the largest value and put it in a column from each row. Per the below, there is a scatter of strings, NaNs and integers.

I guess just running the max function won't work due to the mix of data types.

```
df['max']=df[['team', 'so', 'ibb', 'hpb', 'sh', 'gidp']].max(axis=1)


  df2           so   ibb   hbp    sh    sf  gidp  
year team                                       
2008 DET   176.0   3.0  10.0   4.0   8.0  28.0  
     212.0   3.0   9.0  16.0   6.0  17.0  NaN
     141.0   8.0   9.0   3.0   8.0  29.0  LAN
     310.0  24    NYN   23.0  18.0  15.0  48.0  
     188.0  51.0   8    SFN   16.0   6.0  41.0  
     140.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   8.0  TEX   16.0  
     TOR   265.0  16.0  12.0   4.0  16.0  38.0
```

Comment: If you have a collection, you can apply a conversion function to each, and take the max of that.

Answer (score 1):

If want max numeric value first convert [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['max'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).max(axis=1)
print (df)
                so   ibb   hbp    sh    sf  gidp    max
year  team                                             
2008  DET    176.0   3.0  10.0   4.0   8.0  28.0  176.0
212.0 3.0      9.0  16.0   6.0  17.0   NaN   NaN   17.0
141.0 8.0      9.0   3.0   8.0  29.0   LAN   NaN   29.0
310.0 24       NYN  23.0  18.0  15.0  48.0   NaN   48.0
188.0 51.0       8   SFN  16.0   6.0  41.0   NaN   41.0
140.0 NaN      5.0   NaN   8.0   TEX  16.0   NaN   16.0
TOR   265.0   16.0  12.0   4.0  16.0  38.0   NaN   38.0
```